# Fill parent div on drop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am having a problem with making a div take up all space when dragged and dropped onto another div http://codepen.io/benasl/pen/qaJBPd?editors=0110 .

```
  function dragStart(ev) {
     ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed='move';
     ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.getAttribute('id'));
     ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(ev.target,100,100);
     return true;
  }
  function dragEnter(ev) {
     event.preventDefault();
     return true;
  }

  function dragOver(ev) {
       event.preventDefault();

  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#block").on('dragover',function(ev){
    $("#block").css({"border":"2px dashed black"});
    $("#block").css("background", "#a3a3a3");
    });

    $("#block").on('dragleave',function(ev){
    $("#block").css("border", "none");
    $("#block").css("background", "#d1d1d1");

    });
   });    
  function dragDrop(ev) {
      $("#block").css("border", "none");
     var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
     ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
     ev.stopPropagation();

     return false;
  }
```

EDIT//////////////

I found this simple example of drag and drop http://jsfiddle.net/wj4ak/5/ however still do not know how to make a div fill the parent div when dropped.

Comment: what is issue ?

Comment: I need the blue box to take up full space of the #block element, and to be the size it was at the begining when dragged out of #block element.